# My arraylist is displaying object address not object contents

Tags: java, arraylist, display

arraylist displays object address not actual object , program usesinheritance where salesEmployee is the super class and salesAgent and salesPerson are the subclasses.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class tester {
public static void main(String[]args ) {

ArrayList <salesEmployee> listemps= new ArrayList <salesEmployee>();


Scanner user_input= new Scanner(System.in);


salesPerson emp1 = new salesPerson(); 


emp1.setName("Frank Long");
emp1.setppsNumber(65783);
System.out.println("Enter total value of sales earned by Frank Long");
double valeSale;
valeSale=user_input.nextDouble();
emp1.setvalSale(valeSale);
emp1.getCommission();

listemps.add(emp1);

for ( int j=0; j<listemps.size(); j++ )
      System.out.println("element " + j + ": " + listemps.get(j) );
    }
}
```

This is my salesPerson class

```
public class salesPerson extends salesEmployee{

    public salesPerson() {




    }
    public salesPerson(String name, int ppsNumber, double valSale, double commission) {
        super(name, ppsNumber,valSale,commission);

    }

    public void getCommission() {
        commission=valSale*0.15;
    }

    public String toString2() {

        return toString1()+"value of sales"+getvalSale()+"commission:"+commission;
    }

}
```

I'll make it more elegant later for now I am just trying to get it to work

*Updated:* Based on the comments to my answer, there is a different issue at play. Here's what was added in the comments:

> Enter total value of sales earned by Frank Long 22.00
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError at
>    salesPerson.toString(salesPerson.java:21) at
>    salesPerson.toString(salesPerson.java:21) at
>    salesPerson.toString(salesPerson.java:21) at
>    salesPerson.toString(salesPerson.java:21) – lucylio 5 mins ago
>
> Is what comes up – lucylio 5 mins

Comment: *FYI:* If you want `salesPerson.toString()` to call `salesEmployee.toString()`, you need to use the `super` keyword: `super.toString()`

Comment: *FYI:* Java naming convention is for class names to start with uppercase letter, so classes should be named `SalesEmployee` and `SalesPerson`

Comment: I updated the question with the comments from OP to my answer. Those comments change the question somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

In order for something reasonable to be displayed, you need to implement `toString` method in your class.  You do have `toString1` and `toString2`, but seemingly, no `toString`. (You haven't posted the code for `salesEmployee` class - but most likely it also doesn't have `toString` implementation).

In absence of `toString`, default `Object.toString` is called, which displays the address of the object.

Implement `toString` - and you'll see your results.

**UPDATE:** As the error you indicated doesn't correspond to the code, I'll go on a whim and suggest that, probably your `toString2` method is actually `toString` and your `toString1` method is actually a `toString` defined in your parent class, i.e. `salesEmployee.java`.  In this case, instead of calling `toString()` from inside your `toString` method, use `super.toString()` instead:

```
public class salesPerson extends salesEmployee {

   ...

    public String toString2() {
        return super.toString()+"value of sales"+getvalSale()+"commission:"+commission;
    }
}
```

Comment: Enter total value of sales earned by Frank Long
22.00
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at salesPerson.toString(salesPerson.java:21)
 at salesPerson.toString(salesPerson.java:21)
 at salesPerson.toString(salesPerson.java:21)
 at salesPerson.toString(salesPerson.java:21)

Comment: Is what comes up

Comment: @lucylio This error message does not correspond to the code you posted. You don't have method `toString` at line 21 in `salesPerson.java`

Comment: Almost correct: `Object.toString` doesn't display "the address of the object", it displays the identity hash.

Comment: @JoachimSauer You're correct. The OP used the `address` terminology, I simply went with it.